# Can asylum residents see in the dark?

Tags: outlast

In Outlast, there are patients and inmates in the asylum that are some of the main antagonists in the game. They are called the variants.

During the game, there are scenes that they follow you in the dark.

[image]

Did they somehow adapt the dark environment of the asylum? Or do they have a weakened vision and improved hearing and smelling? Because sometimes, we also hear them sniffing.

I couldn't find any information in the wikia:
http://outlast.wikia.com/wiki/The_Variants

Are there any explanation in the game? For example, in the papers that we find.